# Is there a solution for code bookmarks in the Chrome Debugger, similar to F2 in visual studio?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

What I mean is where you can go to several lines in the code, press Ctrl-F2 and then go back to these code locations by pressing F2 or some other key. I miss this feature a lot (no I do not want to use breakpoints)